# What is the difference between claims repudiated and claims rejected in IRDAI Annual Report?

Tags: india, insurance, life-insurance

Insurance Regulatory and Development Authority is a autonomous body regulating insurance industry in india. It releases an Annual Report every year for providing some statistics and data from industry.

When I am checking the claim settlement ratio in latest English [annual report 2018-19](https://www.irdai.gov.in/admincms/cms/uploadedfiles/annual%20reports/IRDAI%20English%20Annual%20Report%202018-19.pdf) on page number 152, the table has two columns which seems to be same meaning  for me. They are Claims Repudiated and Claims rejected.

What is the difference between claims repudiated and claims rejected in IRDAI Annual Report ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rejected means claims were not processed due to technical errors in submission, i.e. incomplete documents, delayed reporting etc.

Repudiated means that claims were received and processed and determined that insurance company does not have the liability. i.e. not covered in policy etc.

http://www.policyholder.gov.in/Rejection_of_Claims.aspx

Comment: if the claim is rejected because of incomplete documents, can nominee claim again with all necessary documents ?

Comment: @SivaSankaran yes unless it's time-barred. Generally sufficient time is given to rectify the technical errors and if they are not rectified in given time they are rejected. So there needs to be a good reason why the errors were not rectified in stipulated time. Note if the claim gets processed after time bar, it can still be repudiated